# Multiple If Statements Not Working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, get

Yes, I know this looks bad. I am new to JS.

So I'm making a site that gets a user input via a `<select>` value and transfers it to a new page via `form action="result.html" method="GET"`.

There are two `<select>` tags to choose from: One has 40 options, the other has well over 100.

I need a better way to do this, as you can see from my code below it is not only not working but it also takes up way too much space.

Thanks, and if you need any other information I will gladly provide it.

```
var getString = window.location.search;


function getInfo () {
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=1" > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=2") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=3") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=4") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=5") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=6") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=7") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=8") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=9") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=10") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=11") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=12") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=13") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=14") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=15") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=16") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=17") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=18") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=19") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=20") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=21") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=22") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=23") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=24") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=25") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=26") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=27") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=28") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=29") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=30") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=31") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=32") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=33") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=34") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=35") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=36") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=37") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=38") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=39") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=40") > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a for loop

```
var i;
for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) { 
  if (getString.indexOf("devicetype=" + i > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, this works. But for the .innerHTML I want to send a certain message depending on what the device type is. For example, if the device type=2 I want it to say "Your device is an iPad"

Comment: @docyoda so you would have 100 different devices? I would suggest you put them in an array and then you could get them by index like `devices[i]`

Comment: yeah give me 1 sec

Comment: ignore the `var devices = iphones,ipads,ipods` i removed that

Comment: @docyoda you need to do `devices[i -1]` since i is starting at 1 and arrays start at 0. But that probably wont fix your problem.. What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: It says "undefined" when I select a value and click submit.

Comment: I'm trying to get the value of devicetype from the URL and put it into a `<p>` element. Example: if the device type is 1, `<p>` will say iPad 2

Comment: Can you put your code in a codepen or something? I might be able to help you better

Comment: @sasha yes give me one sec

Comment: the js code is from the result page after clicking the finish button

Comment: I think its because there is no `devicetype`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
if (getString.indexOf("devicetype" > -1)) {
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-deviceinfo').innerHTML = "tbd";
    document.getElementById('pleasewait-tip').innerHTML = "tbd";
}
```

since the code does the exact same thing for each case...